# What is the cardinality of the set {a, {a, {a}}}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I think that the answer is 2, but I'm not 100% sure. If the answer isn't 2, could someone help lead me to the correct answer?

Comment: The answer is $2$, because the two elements $a$ and $\{a,\{a\}\}$ are different, else we would have $a\in a$. (This is excluded by set axioms.)

Comment: Sam, where did you get the question? Do you need to prove that $a\neq \{a,\{a\}\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b = \{a,\{a\}\}$. Then your set is $\{a,b\}$ which has $2$ elements, since $a\neq b$. The thing that $b$ is a set with two elements itself doesn't change the number of elements of $\{a,b\}$.

To prove $a\neq b$, assume the contrary. Then, $a\in a$, which is in contradiction with [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: The relation $a\ne b$ needs explanation, this is maybe the only point in the exercise.

Comment: @dan_fulea, I agree, but it's not clear from the question itself.

Comment: Added the proof anyway.

Comment: Thanks for adding the reference to the axiom; presumably OP is using ZF or ZFC (although it's possible that OP doesn't know that).